# Oracle Statement to Return Result Depending on Max Value of a Record

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I've been stuck here for the whole day.

I have 2 tables:

```
TABLE 1: LOGS
FIRST_NAME      LAST_LOG_IN
------------------------------
John            15-NOV-17
Jane            13-NOV-17
John            12-NOV-17
John            11-NOV-17
John            10-NOV-17
Jane            12-NOV-17
```

```
TABLE 2: USER
FIRST_NAME       LAST_NAME    
------------------------------
Jane             Doe
John             Smith
```

**The Requirements are:**

- If today is 22-NOV-17, I need to get the FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME 
  and LAST_LOG_IN(in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' format) of the user 
  only if his/her LAST_LOG_IN is earlier than the last 7 days
- Put only in one statement to execute in SQL Developer (not using PL/SQL)

so the **Expected Output** should be:

```
FIRST_NAME       LAST_NAME        LAST_LOG_IN
---------------------------------------------------
Jane             Doe            2017-11-13 17:49:57
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
select u.first_name, u.last_name, to_char(a.log_date,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from (
  select first_name, max(last_log_in) log_date from logs group by first_name) a
  inner join 
  user u on (a.first_name = u.first_name)
where a.log_date > sysdate - 7;
```

Comment: I think it should be where a.log_date <= sysdate - 7? But I think its working now, @Kacper. Thank you so much :)